# Java String: remove all other whitespaces before and after line breaks

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove heading and tailing whitespaces which is done with `.trim()`, also i need replace all line breaks by single space which is done with `.replaceAll("\\R+", " ")` but before that i need to remove all whitespaces (except line breaks) before and after line break.

```
String toReplace = "\t\t random \t\n\r\t text \t\t";
String result = toReplace.replaceAll(Some magic, "")
                         .replaceAll("\\R+", " ")
                         .trim();

Assert.assertEquals("random text", result);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us an input output example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the whitespaces around the line breaks and remove them together with the line break replacement with space:

```java
String result = toReplace.replaceAll("\\h*\\R+\\h*", " ").trim();
```

The regex is `\h*\R+\h*`, and the `.replaceAll("\\h*\\R+\\h*", " ")` replaces the following pattern sequence with a single regular space:

- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `\R+` - one or more line break sequences
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace